# NHibernate Second Level Cache for Collections is Slow

Tags: performance, caching, nhibernate

I want to store reference data in the 2nd level cache. I found that for queries that return a single entity, this is indeed faster but when the query returns a collection the cache is much slower than accessing the database.

I know that NHibernate does a lot of work assembling entities from key/value pairs when grabbing them from the cache but I am still surprised at how much slower it is.

Let's say my use case is to populate a dropdown with all available languages, it seems as though NHibernate caching does not help at all with this. Is this typical? Does anyone do something similar with better results than me?

As a comparison, storing such a collection in NCache directly is about 400 times faster than what NHibernate caching (with NCache) delivers.

Extract from NHProf;

> -- statement #1
> 2nd level cache load Language (Hrware.Foundation.Infrastructure.Persistence.Temporal.TemporalIdentifier /* id */)
>
> -- statement #2
> 2nd level cache collection load Language.CurrentLocalizations (Hrware.Foundation.Infrastructure.Persistence.Temporal.TemporalIdentifier /* id */)
>
> -- statement #3
> 2nd level cache load LanguageLocalization (Hrware.Foundation.Infrastructure.Persistence.Temporal.TemporalIdentifier /* id */)
>
> -- statement #4
> 2nd level cache load Language (Hrware.Foundation.Infrastructure.Persistence.Temporal.TemporalIdentifier /* id */)
>
> -- statement #5
> 2nd level cache collection load Language.CurrentLocalizations (Hrware.Foundation.Infrastructure.Persistence.Temporal.TemporalIdentifier /* id */)
>
> -- statement #6
> 2nd level cache load LanguageLocalization (Hrware.Foundation.Infrastructure.Persistence.Temporal.TemporalIdentifier /* id */)
>
> -- statement #7
> 2nd level cache load Language (Hrware.Foundation.Infrastructure.Persistence.Temporal.TemporalIdentifier /* id */)

...

and so on

Comment: This may also depend on the relation between your entities (one-one, one-many associations. Could you provide some description of your entites?

Comment: How are you configuring the entities, the collections and the NHibernate cache settings? What second level provider are you using? Are you sure you are hitting the cache?

Comment: My test was with something like the following; Each Language has many LanguageLocalizations (one-many) and I am fetching all Languages. The localizations are eagerly fetched. I am using NHibernate Profiler and I can clearly see the cache hits, for the query cache and the entity cache. I tried this with SysCache2 and NCache and got very similar results.

Comment: Configuration - Language is Cache.ReadWrite() as is its collection of localizations. The query is Cacheable with CacheMode.Normal

Comment: Did you find a solution for this? I am caching collections of few thousand items and the hydration is killing me...